# How to get BURG on 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal)

Tags: 12.10, grub2, repository, burg

I've been using BURG for years to get rid of the eye sore that is the standard GRUB interface. When I upgraded to Quantal, the repository does not contain the updated information. I.e. after I add

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the annoying response

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/burg/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

It's been like this for a month, contrary to various websites which say it works.

Is BURG being maintained? Have they created a better alternative (such as integration with GRUB, like it should have been in the first place). How do I get a decent-looking bootloader?

Comment: possibly they hav not update repo for 12.10. contact ppa owner

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

Comment: I did some digging and apparently it hasn't changed since 12.04 (which the repository has an entry for). Any chance of using the Precise Pangolin version from the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to go into Software Sources. Open the dash and type software. Software Sources will pop up in the dash; click to open it.

Click on the Other Software tab and you will see the BURG PPAs towards the bottom of the field.

Click on the first entry (the one without '(Source Code)' at the end). Then click edit below the list box. The Edit dialog will appear.

Change the **quantal** entry in the Distribution field to **precise**. This is to use the binaries for 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin).

Save, and do the steps above for the source code entry. Save that, and then run this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

That should then make Ubuntu use the Precise repositories for BURG. Then just install burg with your commands.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and Just run following command.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg -y && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes grub-customizer
```

You will get burg installed.

Comment: No joy, I'm afraid. Same as before

Comment: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`

Comment: This does not answer the question. With the given parameters he is unable to perform the required update.